# MahApps.Metro Demo Application как запустить

Tags: c#, wpf, github

склонировал репозиторий отсюда https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro
но проект не компилируется. количество ошибок слишком велико, чтобы их исправлять (да и врятли там ошибки. скорее я чето не так делаю)
ищу то приложение что в описании 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

собственно вопрос в следующем: как скомпилировать проект? (или если в репозитории его нет, то где найти)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем компилировать самостоятельно? Скомпилированная демо-версия (как на вашем скриншоте) находится в разделе [Releases](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/releases/latest) этого репозитория.

1. [Скомпилированная демка](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/releases/download/1.5.0/MetroDemo.zip)
2. [Исходный код](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/archive/1.5.0.zip)

---

Для восстановления всех зависимостей выполните команду

```
.paket/paket.exe install
```

в консоли менеджера пакетов.

Затем `Build Solution` (Ctrl+Shift+B)

Comment: мне б исходный код увидеть. хочется же еще и увидеть как реализовано

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr исходный код там же. https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/archive/1.5.0.zip

Comment: 27 ошибок 84 предупреждения в исходном. я уже качал этот репозиторий. даж конструктор формы не открывает

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr а вы восстановили nuget-пакеты для этого солюшена?

Comment: нет. пишет
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr у меня получилось собрать решение, см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: вроде скомпилился, но потом упал. ну все же прогресс есть

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr вам нужно запускать проект `MahApps.Metro.Demo.NET45` [результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPbqb.png)

Comment: он нормально запускается, но не всегда открывается в конструкторе. я не знаю как это может быть)

Comment: @AlexandrAlexandr не совсем понятно - вопрос решен или нет?

Comment: решен. запустить то получилось. баги vs 2015 разбирать гденить в другом месте буду